# MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Driver -- it returned 3

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF API that is supposed to feed a frontend Android and IOS app. The API has three types of users namely: Driver, Client and Admin.

The client is supposed to create a booking record and get assigned a driver automatically by the API. Based on availability days and times. At the moment every day (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri) is a working day and working hours range from 7:00 am to 9:00 pm with working hours inclusive of transition being an hour. For example, booking of 9:00am will take an hour, hence finishing time will be 10:00am, all factors inclusive. Many drivers can have work at the same time. The app should give feedback to the user if they try booking already picked slots.

My problem at this time is to loop through already existing drivers from drivers table, left join them to the booking table and and assign them one by one. I was able to assign one driver a job. But when I added drivers, it became difficult. There is something I am not getting well and I do not know what it is.

Here are my models.

```
""" models.py """


    """ Helper function to check overlapping times """
    def check_time_overlap(self, fixed_start, fixed_end, new_start, new_end):
        time_overlap = False
        if new_start == fixed_end or new_end == fixed_start:  # edge case
            time_overlap = False
        elif (new_start >= fixed_start and new_start <= fixed_end) or \
                (new_end >= fixed_start and new_end <= fixed_end):  \
                # innner limits
            time_overlap = True
        elif new_start <= fixed_start and new_end >= fixed_end: \
                # outter limits
            time_overlap = True

        return time_overlap

    """ Function to check overlapping bookings """
    def overlapping_bookings(self):
        if self.finishing_at <= self.booking_time:
            raise ValidationError(
                'Finishing times must be after booking times'
            )

        bookings = Booking.objects.filter(
            booking_date=self.booking_date, driver_id=self.driver
        )
        if bookings.exists():
            for booking in bookings:
                """ Check whether date and time overlaps """
                if self.check_time_overlap(
                    booking.booking_time, booking.finishing_at,
                    self.booking_time, self.finishing_at
                ):
                    """ If all drivers are allocated, raise an error \
                        message. """
                    raise ValidationError(
                        'All our drivers are booked at: ' +
                        str(booking.booking_date) + ', ' + str(
                            booking.booking_time) + '-' +
                        str(booking.finishing_at))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.calc_booking_total()
        self.calc_finishing_at()
        self.overlapping_bookings()
        super(Booking, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

From the above models, I have written a function to check overlapping times for the same booking_date, booking_time and finishing_at times. This is inspired by **ALEXANDRE PINTO** on >https://alexpnt.github.io/2017/07/15/django-calendar/

Below are the serializers

```
# BOOKING SERIALIZER
# ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––#


class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    package = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    vehicle_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    client_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    client_phone = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('driver',)
        read_only_fields = (
            'booking_total', 'booking_status',
            'booked_at', 'finishing_at', 'client'
        )

    def get_package(self, obj):
        return obj.service.package_name

    def get_vehicle_type(self, obj):
        return obj.service.vehicle_category.name

    def get_client_name(self, obj):
        return obj.client.name

    def get_client_phone(self, obj):
        return str(obj.client.phone)

    """ Function to create booking based on authenticated client and available drivers """
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['client'] = self.context['request'].user
        validated_data['driver'] = Driver.objects.get(active=True)

        bookings = Booking.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return bookings
```

Here are my server logs:

[Server Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTkeb.png)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, Thanks for equipping me with this knowledge. I will do better in my next post

Comment: @PeterMburu, you should not change the question, your problem is solved by using `.filter()[0]`. i left it for you to think more, in order to change to `get.`

Comment: This is a *very* long question.  Try to reduce the problem to as little code as possible, and clearly indicate where the error is occuring.  The way this is written we must read and understand your entire api.

Comment: That said, you have multiple results.  `get()` will error.  If you want the first one you an just call `.first()`, or use the `.fitler(thing=x)[0]` slice notation to take the top one.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Below is a solution I created to the following problem. Any one can perfect it. Note: It gets help from the function `overlapping_bookings()` in order to stop anymore bookings for a single date and time once all drivers are allocated. This throws in a ValidationError from `overlapping_bookings()` on `save()`

I hope it helps someone

In `serializers.py`, the function is overriding `ModelViewSet` `create`.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Function to create booking objects \
        and allocate drivers automatically. """

        validated_data['client'] = self.context['request'].user

        """ Variable to save all drivers (querysets) from the driver \
        table ordered by the booking date and time. --> maybe there is \
        a better way to do it. Avoid using .get()"""

        drivers = Driver.objects.filter(active=True).order_by(
            '-booking__booking_date', '-booking__booking_time').all()

        """ Check whether the drivers querysets (list) exists """
        if drivers.exists():

            """ For loop to isolate a single query set from list of \
            quersets (drivers) """
            for drv in drivers:

                """ Condition to check for inner join query between \
                driver and booking table carefully filtering them using \
                booking_date and booking_time. This code is helped by \
                the clean() function in models. Which after every active=True \
                driver is allocated a booking, raises a ValidationError. \

                It is subject to be made better. Trying to find out how it \
                will throw a HttpResponse error instead."""

                if Booking.objects.select_related('driver').filter(
                    booking_date=validated_data['booking_date'],
                    booking_time=validated_data['booking_time'],
                ).annotate(drv=F('driver__user_ptr')).exists():
                    continue
            try:
                return Booking.objects.create(driver=drv, **validated_data)
            except Booking.DoesNotExist:
                pass
```