# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable | DRF exception handling

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to parse Django model ValidationError into DRF ValidationError. But I keep getting the following output:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here is the model function:
To avoid repetition: I will paste the link to the previous question which has the model function.

[models.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521898/multipleobjectsreturned-get-returned-more-than-one-driver-it-returned-3?noredirect=1#comment108836182_61521898)

Here is my custom exception handler:

```
import logging

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError as DjangoValidationError
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def transform_exception(exception):
    """Transform model validation errors into an equivalent \
    DRF ValidationError.
    After reading the references, you may decide not to use this.

    References:
    https://www.kye.id.au/blog/understanding-django-rest-framework-model-full-clean/
    https://www.dabapps.com/blog/django-models-and-encapsulation/
    """
    if isinstance(exception, DjangoValidationError):
        if hasattr(exception, "message_dict"):
            detail = exception.message_dict
        elif hasattr(exception, "message"):
            detail = exception.message
        elif hasattr(exception, "messages"):
            detail = exception.messages
        else:
            LOG.error("BAD VALIDATION MESSAGE: %s", exception)

        exception = ValidationError(detail=detail)

    return exception
```

And here is my error log:

[Server Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpJ9s.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you add Model class?

Comment: @narendra-choudhary Please refer to my question for improvements as you asked.

Comment: Check your drf settings block in settings.py file. There is a var `EXCEPTION_HANDLER`. This var should contains a func not list